# How to fix F1.Help Visual studio 2019 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When working in visual studio I have discovered that the F1.F1Help shortcut now redirects me to a google search instead of the MSDN page. This is for all that I have tested (including pages I know exists like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0).

I am running Visual Studio 2019 and have resharper installed. I am using the resharper key bindings but when I change back to C# 2005 I have the same issue. I also have tried reinstalling visual studio and repairing but I am in the same situation.

How can I debug or fix this issue?

Comment: It seems to work for me.  Only difference is I don't have resharper.  Perhaps check if resharper is remapping F1 to something else.

Comment: This is a bug within rider. Appears fixed with resharper. No answer as of yet.